# Securing access to PHP API

Tags: php, ios, rest, hash

I have an iPhone app that is using my PHP API on the server but it is currently open if someone knows the URL. I want to make sure that no one can use this API until I am ready to make it a public API (if I even do).

I have read [this article](http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/designing-a-secure-rest-api-without-oauth-authentication/) but I am unsure what they mean when they say:

> [CLIENT] Before making the REST API call, combine a bunch of unique data together (this is typically all the parameters and values you intend on sending, it is the “data” argument in the code snippets on AWS’s site)

I don't understand how if I hash the parameters I plan on sending with my api secret how this is more secure than just hashing the API secret if I send the parameters/values unencrypted.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Securing web-API access](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3130969/securing-web-api-access)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HTTPS the API and use an API key.  Then you'll know that only people (you in this case) with the key can have access to the API.

You're correct about it not being more secure.  That's why I suggest you SSL the connection.  Unless you plan on encrypting everything you transmit back and forth.

The public/private key scenario will also work well.  HTTPS requires very **minimal effort**.

Answer (score 2):

[Digital signatures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature) provide a way of validating a message sent over an insecure connection.

Setup: each client will have its own **private key** and **public key** (only the private key needs to be stored on the client). The server will store the public keys for each client. The public key can be visible to all and can be used by the server to identify the client. The private key, known only to the client, it is never shown to anyone.

The client signs the request: along with the rest of the request data, the client will hash the combined request data and encrypt the hash with the private key. The server will generate the hash the same way (leaving the signature out of the hash calculation), then decrypt the signature using the public key. If the hashes match, the request is authentic.

Note that HTTPS allows for client certificates, so you can leverage existing tools to accomplish all of the above without writing a single line of server-side code (you just have to configure your web server; the only trick is to make sure the server only accepts certificates it already has). Moreover, the amount of client side code should be minimal: you shouldn't need to do much more than set the connection to use the client certificate. Since you're controlling the clients, you can use self-signed certificates and add the server as a certificate authority. There are a number of questions on SO about using [client certificates in iPhone apps](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=iPhone%20HTTPS%20%2bclient%20%2bcertificate&submit=search); you can start by reading through them.

Note also that any scheme to protect the web API only works so long as copies of the app are in trusted hands. Should anyone untrustworthy get ahold of it, they can use the app or extract any secret data used by the app and access the API as they will.

Comment: OK that's my questions though, why do you combine data and hash it with api secret? send that, and then send the unencrypted data? how is this more secure than just hashing the api secret?

Comment: @mkral: It's not, you're confused. You combine things like prefixes and suffixes, along with multiplying the hashing algorithm, possible combine the user's ID and username there too. It's unrelated to the actual data you're sending, you're sending it alongside with everything else.

Comment: Private keys should be known only to the client. If there's a database vulnerability on the server, the private keys can be stolen.

Answer (score 0):

For development purposes you can just use your web server settings to allow requests from your ip only.

Comment: Well I'm not talking about development purposes, I want to have an api key/secret within the iphone app. so any iphone running my app will use my api key. in the future, If I plan on opening the api for other uses I want to make sure it's protected.