# Implementation of a secure API server

Tags: javascript, php, json, rest, authentication

I am looking on securing a pseudo-api server I am building in php.

Here is a very basic form of the api.php :

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['type']) ) {
switch ($_GET['type']) {
case  'combobox'  :
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$an_array = array();
$an_array[0]['id'] = 'Option 1';
$an_array[0]['text'] = 'Option 1';
$an_array[1]['id'] = 'Option 2';
$an_array[1]['text'] = 'Option 2';
echo json_encode($an_array);
break;
default:
echo 'nothing to see here as type was not a valid option';
break;
}
}
else {
  echo 'no type specified';
}
 ?>
```

The above when called http://example.com/api.php?type=combobox will return the following json :

```
[{"id":"Option 1","text":"Option 1"},{"id":"Option 2","text":"Option 2"}]
```

This json could be consumed in a combobox using ajax as follows :

Content of call.php :

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.1/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
  <select class="select2 select2-single" single data-placeholder="Select Types">
  <optgroup label="Types">
  </optgroup>
  </select>


<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".select2").select2({
   width: '300px',
   ajax: {
     url: "http://example.com/json.php?type=combobox",
     dataType: 'json',
     delay: 250,
     multiple: "false",
     dropdownAutoWidth: 'true',
     processResults: function (data) {
       return {
         results: $.map(data, function (obj) {
           return {
             id: obj.id,
             text: obj.text
           };
         })
       };
     }
   }
 });
})
 </script>
```

In practice, I have a server that serves a web application that has this combobox and hundreds of other things and is calling the api server to query mysql etc. As those ajax calls are happening from the browser of the user and are populating comboboxes and datatables, i cannot just lock the ip of the web application server to the api server. I could get the user session and do something with it though.
Problem is, that I want to give to a third party access to query this api return securely.

I was thinking maybe I could grab the php session once logged in and pass it to the api server, then serve content to the browser only if this session is active. But this does not solve my problem of giving some data feeds to a third party (that will not have a session to the web application).

I am not trying to reinvent the wheel here, I am open to any suggestions using any framework or way to do this properly and securely.

I guess the solution would involve querying the api server like that : json.php?type=combobox&apikey=xxxxxxxxrandomxxxxxxxxx
where the apikey is something that someone cannot just take from the sourcecode and run it on another machine?

Comment: Please clarify what exactly you're trying to protect against?

Comment: I want for example , this json data you see above to be viewable only from a user logged in to my web application (using php authentication) or a third party that has a key or other means that I have issued to them. I dont want this data to be viewable publically if someone just types the url in the browser.

Comment: Then you're looking at something like an OAuth implementation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Securing access to PHP API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11350989/securing-access-to-php-api)